# Composing Option with List in for-comprehension gives type mismatch depending on order

Tags: scala, for-loop, type-mismatch, for-comprehension, scala-option

Why does this construction cause a Type Mismatch error in Scala?

```
for (first <- Some(1); second <- List(1,2,3)) yield (first,second)

<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Int, Int)]
 required: Option[?]
       for (first <- Some(1); second <- List(1,2,3)) yield (first,second)
```

If I switch the Some with the List it compiles fine:

```
for (first <- List(1,2,3); second <- Some(1)) yield (first,second)
res41: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (2,1), (3,1))
```

This also works fine:

```
for (first <- Some(1); second <- Some(2)) yield (first,second)
```

Comment: What result did you expect Scala to return in the failing example?

Comment: When I was writing it I thought I would get an Option[List[(Int,Int)]].

Answer (score 120, accepted):

For comprehensions are converted into calls to the `map` or `flatMap` method. For example this one:

```
for(x <- List(1) ; y <- List(1,2,3)) yield (x,y)
```

becomes that:

```
List(1).flatMap(x => List(1,2,3).map(y => (x,y)))
```

Therefore, the first loop value (in this case, `List(1)`) will receive the `flatMap` method call. Since `flatMap` on a `List` returns another `List`, the result of the for comprehension will of course be a `List`. (This was new to me: For comprehensions don't always result in streams, not even necessarily in `Seq`s.)

Now, take a look at how `flatMap` is declared in `Option`:

```
def flatMap [B] (f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]) : Option[B]
```

Keep this in mind. Let's see how the erroneous for comprehension (the one with `Some(1)`) gets converted to a sequence of map calls:

```
Some(1).flatMap(x => List(1,2,3).map(y => (x, y)))
```

Now, it's easy to see that the parameter of the `flatMap` call is something that returns a `List`, but not an `Option`, as required.

In order to fix the thing, you can do the following:

```
for(x <- Some(1).toSeq ; y <- List(1,2,3)) yield (x, y)
```

That compiles just fine. It is worth noting that `Option` is not a subtype of `Seq`, as is often assumed.

Answer (score 34):

An easy tip to remember, *for comprehensions* will try to return the type of the collection of the first generator, Option[Int] in this case. So, if you start with *Some(1)* you should expect a result of Option[T].

If you want a result of *List* type, you should start with a List generator.

Why have this restriction and not assume you'll always want some sort of sequence? You can have a situation where it makes sense to return `Option`. Maybe you have an `Option[Int]` that you want to combine with something to get a `Option[List[Int]]`, say with the following function: `(i:Int) => if (i > 0) List.range(0, i) else None`; you could then write this and get None when things don't "make sense":

```
val f = (i:Int) => if (i > 0) Some(List.range(0, i)) else None
for (i <- Some(5); j <- f(i)) yield j
// returns: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
for (i <- None; j <- f(i)) yield j
// returns: Option[List[Int]] = None
for (i <- Some(-3); j <- f(i)) yield j
// returns:  Option[List[Int]] = None
```

How *for comprehensions* are expanded in the general case are in fact a fairly general mechanism to combine an object of type `M[T]` with a function `(T) => M[U]` to get an object of type `M[U]`. In your example, M can be Option or List. In general it has to be the same type `M`. So you can't combine Option with List. For examples of other things that can be `M`, look at [subclasses of this trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/FilterMonadic.html).

Why did combining `List[T]` with `(T) => Option[T]` work though when you started with the List? In this case the library use a more general type where it makes sense. So you can combine List with Traversable and there is an implicit conversion from Option to Traversable.

The bottom line is this: think about what type you want the expression to return and start with that type as the first generator. Wrap it in that type if necessary.

Comment: I'd argue that it's a bad design choice to make regular `for` syntax do this type of functor / monadic desugaring. Why not have differently named methods for functor /monad mapping, like `fmap`, etc., and reserve `for` syntax to have an extremely simple behavior that matches expectations coming from virtually any other mainstream programming language?

Comment: You can make the separate fmap / lift sort of stuff as generic as you like without making a mainstream sequential computing control flow statement become very surprising and have nuanced performance complications, etc. "Everything works with for" is not worth that.

Answer (score 5):

It probably has something to do with Option not being an Iterable. The implicit [`Option.option2Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$@option2Iterable[A]%28xo:Option[A]%29:Iterable[A]) will handle the case where compiler is expecting second to be an Iterable. I expect that the compiler magic is different depending on the type of the loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

I always found this helpful:

```
scala> val foo: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
foo: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> foo.flatten
<console>:13: error: Cannot prove that Seq[Int] <:< Option[B].
   foo.flatten
       ^

scala> val bar: Seq[Seq[Int]] = Seq(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
bar: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> bar.flatten
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> foo.toSeq.flatten
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8038) Option was made `IterableOnce`

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends IterableOnce[A] with Product with Serializable
```

so the following for comprehension works without the use of `option2Iterable` implicit conversion

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- List(1)
     |   b <- Some(41)
     | } yield (a + b)
val res35: List[Int] = List(42)

scala> List(1).flatMap
final override def flatMap[B](f: Int => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

where we see `List#flatMap` takes a function to `IterableOnce`. Desugaring above for comprehension we get something like

```
List(1).flatMap(a => Some(41).map(b => a + b))
```

which show the absence of the implicit conversion.

However in Scala 2.12 and before `Option` was not a traversable/iterable entity

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable
```

so the above for comprehension would desugar to something like

```
List(1).flatMap(a => option2Iterable(Some(41)).map(b => a + b))(List.canBuildFrom[Int])
```

where we see the implicit conversion.

The reason it does not work the other way around where for comprehension begins with `Option` and then we try to chain a `List`

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- Option(1)
     |   b <- List(41)
     | } yield (a + b)
         b <- List(41)
           ^
On line 3: error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[Int]
        required: Option[?]

scala> Option(1).flatMap
final def flatMap[B](f: Int => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

is because `Option#flatMap` takes a function to `Option` and converting a `List` to `Option` probably does not make sense because we would lose elements for `List`s with more than one element.

As [szeiger](https://gitter.im/scala/contributors?at=5ce542c2ad024978c60c7179) explains

> I think the recent `Option` changes actually make the for comprehensions
> use case easier to understand because you do not need an implicit
> conversion anymore. `Option` can be used on the RHS of a `flatMap` of any
> collection type because it is `IterableOnce` (but not the opposite
> because the RHS of `Option#flatMap` requires `Option`).