# Remedial syntax issue with for-comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

I'm having syntax issues with a for-comprehension in Scala 2.10.

`for(a <- List(Some(1,2)); b <- a) yield b` evaluates to `List(1,2)`

so why doesn't `for(a <- Some(List(1,2)); b <- a) yield b` evaluate to the same thing?

The type-checker complains about the second expression (`b <-a`) saying it found a `List[Int]`
when expecting an `Option[?]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type Mismatch on Scala For Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension)

Comment: it's also duplicate of [Confused with the for-comprehension to flatMap/Map transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've explained this very recently -- hopefully someone can find the link. It's a recurring question, so it may well be closed.

At any rate, the outer generator controls the representation. That happens on each level, so if I have this:

```
for { 
  a <- A
  b <- B
  c <- C
} yield f(a, b, c)
```

Then the representation of `f(a, b, c)` is controlled by `C`, the representation of that is controlled by `B`, and the representation of the final result is controlled by `A`. So, for most practical purposes, the representation of the for comprehension is controlled by the first generator.

So what do I mean by "representation"? Well, a for comprehension is a monadic comprehension, usually (actually, it's just a set of calls to methods like `flatMap` and `map`, so it can be *anything* that typechecks). That means that given a monad `M[A]` and a function `A => M[B]`, then you can transform `M[A]` in `M[B]`, where `M`, the monad, is the "representation".

This means that, for the most part, it would be impossible to combine `Option` and `List` in a for comprehension. All the collections have a common parent in `GenTraversableOnce`, so there's no problem in combining them (though things are much more complicated than that under the hood).

However, there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable`. That being the case, when Scala finds `b <- a` in the first example, and knowing it can't pass an `Option` because the comprehension is being "controlled" by a `List`, it converts the `Option` into an `Iterable`, and everything works.

However, that doesn't happen in the second case. Doing a for comprehension with an `Option` is ok, so there's no need to convert it into an `Iterable`. Unfortunately, one cannot convert a `List` into an `Option` (what would be the result of such a conversion?), which results in the error.

Scala will not "backtrack" to `a <- Some(List(1, 2))` and apply an implicit conversion to it, as type inference in Scala only goes forward -- what it decided before will remain as is.

I heartily recommend you look at the related questions and understand how a for comprehension is translated.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I wouldn't be surprised if the question is a duplicate because it is hard to search for and the "Tour of Scala" doc on comprehensions doesn't explain this behaviour. The thing which really tripped me up was that for(a <- Some(List(1,2)); b <- a){println(b)} behaves as I expect, namely 'b' evaluates to the underlying Ints.

Comment: @DanielSchobel Well, in the absence of `yield`, you are not returning anything, so there's no problem. Since you can't have a `Some(1, 2)`, you can't have the `yield` version.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel explained the intricacies of this. But I would like to add some detail, because as you I find this behaviour incredibly unintuitive, and I have come across this problem of mixing `Option` and `List` a few times myself. It is especially annoying, because as you see, it works in one direction but not the other.

So according to the for-comprehension rules you'll have

```
def test(a: Option[List[Int]]) = a.flatMap(_.map(identity))
```

failing with

```
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
           def test(a: Option[List[Int]]) = a.flatMap(_.map(identity))
                                                           ^
```

But you can make it work:

```
def test(a: Option[List[Int]]) = (a: Iterable[List[Int]]).flatMap(_.map(identity))

test(Some(List(1,2)))  // List(1,2)
```

Or back with `for`:

```
for(a <- Some(List(1,2)).toIterable; b <- a) yield b
```

Should `for` impose this conversion by itself? I don't know honestly, but I share your surprise that it doesn't work.

Comment: Upvoted for the work-around, and I agree, it does seem like it _should_ work in its original form, especially as I point out in my comment to Daniel that for(a <- Some(List(1,2)); b <- a){println(b)} works exactly as you would expect, namely, b evals to the underlying Ints.