# How to return different collection with yield statement

Tags: scala

Based on my limited knowledge i know compiler automatically inherits the collection return type and based on that it determines the type of collection to return so in below code i want to return `Option[Vector[String]]`.

I tried to experiment with below code and i get compilation error

```
type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]  required: Option[Vector[String]]
```

**Code:**

```
def readDocument(v:Option[Vector[String]]) : Option[Vector[String]] =    
{
   for ( a <- v;  
   b <- a )
     yield 
     {
        b
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
  def readDocument(ovs: Option[Vector[String]]): Option[Vector[String]] =
    for (vs <- ovs) yield for (s <- vs) yield s
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> for (v <- Some(Vector("abc")); e <- v) yield e
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]
 required: Option[?]
              for (v <- Some(Vector("abc")); e <- v) yield e
                                               ^

scala> for (v <- Some(Vector("abc")); e = v) yield e
res1: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]] = Some(Vector(abc))
```

A nested `x <- xs` means [`flatMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield) and will work only when the returned type is the same type as [the most outer one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension).

Comment: or `for (v <- Some(Vector("abc"))) yield v`

Answer (score 0):

The `for` comprehension already unboxes for you `Option` so this should work

```
def readDocument(v:Option[Vector[String]]) : Option[Vector[String]] =    
{
  for ( a <- v )
  yield 
  {
    a
  }
}
```