# For comprehension with Map lookup - is there a better way?

Tags: scala, dictionary, for-comprehension

Consider the following

```
val myMap: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map("a" -> List(1,2,3), 
                                        "b" -> List(4,5,6), 
                                        "d" -> List(7))

val possibleKeys: List[String] = List("c","a", "b", "e")
```

I would like to traverse the possible keys, and if the map contains one, traverse the map's values

The options I came up with are:

**With a filter**

```
 for {
    key <- possibleKeys
    if (myMap contains key)
    int <- myMap(key)
    r <- 0 to int
  } yield (r, int)
```

**With `getOrElse`**

```
  for {
    key <- possibleKeys
    int <- myMap.getOrElse(key, Nil)
    r <- 0 to int
  } yield (r, int)
```

(Both return the same result:)

```
List((0,1), (1,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (0,4), (1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (0,5), (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5), (5,5), (0,6), (1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6), (5,6), (6,6))
```

Since I know Scala supports Options in for comprehensions, I was a bit surprised that this didn't work

```
for {
    key <- possibleKeys
    int <- myMap.get(key)
    r <- 0 to int //<-- compilation error
  } yield (r, int)
```

It complains about `type mismatch;  found   : List[Int]  required: Int`

Which I vaguely understand why, but is there a way to make this work without the `if` clause or the `getOrElse` methods? (e.g. is there a way to get the `myMap.get(key)` version to work?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, your code doesn't seem to match your description. What is the `r <- 0 to int` doing there, other than just counting up? From your verbal description, I'd assume you'd want to omit that step and just yield `(key, int)` so I'm wondering what the `r` is doing :)

Comment: @MyseriousDan just to illustrate that I intend using the result as the input of some other iteration, the verbal description is incomplete, will fix the description, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to mix incompatible types  in your for comprehension. You can fix it by converting the option to a Seq by example.

```
for {
  key <- possibleKeys
  ints <- myMap.get(key).toSeq
  int <- ints
  r <- 0 to int
} yield (r, int)
```

There is a rather nice explanation of the problem in this very similar question here: [Type Mismatch on Scala For Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the methods `keySet` and `apply` on [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map)

```
for {
  key <- possibleKeys
  if myMap.keySet(key)
  int <- myMap(key)
  r <- 0 to int
} yield (r, int)

res5: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (1,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (0,4), (1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (0,5), (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5), (5,5), (0,6), (1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6), (5,6), (6,6))
```