# Calling a web service that depends on a result from another web service in play framework

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to call a second web service with the result from the first one.
Below is some code that highlights my intent. 
By the way it compiles fine in IntelliJ(Probable a bug in the IDE).

```
  def get = {
    for {
      respA <- WS.url(url1).get
      id <- respA.body.split(",").take(2)
      respB <- WS.url(url2 + id).get // Here is a compile error
    } yield {
      getMyObjects(respB.xml)
    }
  }
```

- **respA** = is a comma separated list with ids used in the next call.
- **respB** = is an XML response that I parse in the yield method

The compile error `Play Framework` gives me:

```
type mismatch; 
found : scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[MyObject]] 
required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

I find the compile error strange.

1. How can a `Future` of `[Seq[MyObject]]` exist at that line?
2. It shouldn't be any different from the line two lines up that compiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WS.url(url1).get` returns `Future[Response]` so all your generators in the *for* comprehension should be futures. In your code snippet, you are mixing `Array[String]` and `Future[Response]`. See [Type Mismatch on Scala For Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension/4720758#4720758) for some background on *for* comprehension.

So I would try something like this:

```
for {
  respA <- WS.url(url1).get
  ids = respA.body.split(",").take(2)
  responsesB <- Future.sequence(ids.map(id => WS.url(url2 + id).get))
} yield {
  responsesB.map(respB => getMyObjects(respB.xml))
}
```

So the types are:

```
respA: Response
ids: Array[String]
ids.map(id => WS.url(url2 + id).get): Array[Future[Response]]
Future.sequence(ids.map(id => WS.url(url2 + id).get)): Future[Array[Response]]
responsesB: Array[Response]
```

And the return type of the *for* comprehension is a `Future` of an array of whatever `getMyObjects` returns.

Note that if *sequence* does not work on `Future[Array[_]]` try to do `ids = respA.body.split(",").toList.take(2)`.