# for comprehensions with if guard throws error

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension, either

I get one error when I use for comprehensions with if guard in this way.

code:

```
for {
  foo <- Left[String,String]("teststring").right
  bar <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right if (foo==bar)
} yield (bar)
```

error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[scala.util.Either[Nothing,String]]
 required: scala.util.Either[?,?]
                bar <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right if (foo==bar)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix above error. I also move if-guard to later process.

```
val result = for {
  foo <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right
  bar <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right
} yield (foo, bar)

result fold (
  ex => Left("Operation failed with " + ex),
  v => v match { 
    case (x,y) =>
        if (x == y) Right(x)
        else Left("value is different")
  } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do since the types of all statements in a `for`-comprehension [need to be of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension), and the `if (foo == bar)` filter expression makes the last expression an `Option[Either[?,?]]` instead of `Either[?,?]`.

One way to get around this is to desugar the expression into a series of `flatMap`, `map` and `filter` expressions.

Another way is to lose the the Left of either, and just use the `toOption` method on the RightProjection, i.e.:

```
for {
  foo <- Left[String,String]("left").right.toOption
  bar <- Right[String,String]("right").right.toOption if (foo == bar)
} yield (foo)
```