# Why doesn't Option inherit from Seq and Set?

Tags: scala, inheritance, scala-collections

I have two questions but I expect the answers are intertwined. So I was playing around with flatMapping different parametric types. I get the following:

```
val s: List[String] = List("f2", "df", "e")     //> s  : List[String] = List(f2, df, e)
val o = s.map(s => if (s.head == 'f')Some(s) else None)
                                              //> o  : List[Option[String]] = List(Some(f2), None, None)
val o1 = s.flatMap(s => if (s.head == 'f')Some(s) else None)
                                              //> o1  : List[String] = List(f2)
val a: Option[String] = Some("Hello")           //> a  : Option[String] = Some(Hello)
val a1 = a.map(s => s.toList)                   //> a1  : Option[List[Char]] = Some(List(H, e, l, l, o))
```

but

```
val a2 = a.flatMap(s => s.toList) //gives
//type mismatch;  found   : List[Char]  required: Option[?]
```

So I'm trying to understand the logic behind o1 compiling but not a2. And then looking into Option I was wondering why Option doesn't inherit from the traits: Seq and Set? Option is a Seq as it maintains order, and it is a Set because it contains no duplicates. Through Seq and Set it would inherit from Iterable and Traversable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumption for all `GenTraversableOnce` descendants is that they contain an *arbitrary* number of elements. There's too much of the API and the mechanics that assumes or depends on that, such as `Builder` and `CanBuildFrom`.

On a deeper level, however, it is important to realize that for-comprehensions, and `map`/`flatMap`, are *monadic* operations. Monads are not interchangeable -- you cannot pick a a function `A => N[B]` and pass it to an `M[A]` to get an `N[B]`, for any monad M and N, and `Option` and collections are *different* monads.

Through much implicit magic, all of the collections are treated as if they were a single monad, which leads people to assume that all monads *should* be interchangeable, which is simply not the case.

Then consider a simple case like this:

```
val x = Option(1)
val y = List('a', 'b', 'c')
val z = for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
} yield (a, b)
```

The type of `z` *cannot* be an `Option`, since the result has multiple elements. The only way for it to work would be for it to become something like an `Iterable`. That might make some sense for `Option`, if you think of it as a collection of at most one element, but it would not make sense for things like a `State` or `Reader` monad.

And speaking of thinking of `Option` as a collection of at most one, that is another reason not to do it. An `Option` should be thought of as the presence or absence of an element, not as a collection, and the methods available on which help this subtle distinction. Then again, I know of many people who think this argument, at least, is completely bogus, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to map over an Option it is not a sequence nor a set (with only one element).

Flat map on option is defined like this

```
flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So it wants a function that returns another Option. Your code

```
a.flatMap(s => s.toList)
```

does not return an Option[_] but a list of characters (s is a String and s.toList returns a List[Char]).

Comment: I guess the question wasn't *is Option set or sequence?*. The question is more like *WHY library design was done in a way that Option does not inherits from this two traits* -- e.g. there is some known downside that stops one from implementing Option in this particular way.

Comment: And by the way -- [last point about List/Option type mismatch is a common confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension)