# Converting flatMap to for-comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, flatmap

Given `foo` and `bar`:

```
scala> def foo: Try[Seq[String]] = Success(List("good", "job"))
foo: scala.util.Try[Seq[String]]

scala> def bar(x: String): Try[String] = Try(x)
bar: (x: String)scala.util.Try[String]
```

How can I convert this `flatMap` into a `for-comprehension`?

```
scala> foo.flatMap(a => Try(a.map(c => bar(c))))
res48: scala.util.Try[Seq[scala.util.Try[String]]] = 
         Success(List(Success(good), Success(job)))
```

Note that I provided the above as an answer to [Using for-comprehension, Try and sequences in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23265227/409976), but I'm having trouble converting it to a `for-comphension`.

Comment: So you want a single `Try[Seq]` or do you want `Seq[Try]`? Also, does one `Failure` fail the entire thing in the first case? Is an empty `Seq` synonymous with `Failure`?

Comment: good question. I suppose a `Try[Seq[Try[String]]]` doesn't make any sense. what do you understand the return type to be in the question that I mentioned - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265227/using-for-comprehension-try-and-sequences-in-scala?

Comment: Why do you cast the Success to a Try in your first function?

Comment: It's quite typical to cast ADTs like this, @AndreasNeumann. ML/OCaml and Haskell do it automatically, so to speak; e.g. the type of `Just 3` is `Maybe Int` in Haskell; Scala doesn't have true ADTs so explicit casts are necessary to imitate these semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A for-comprehension can only be a sequence of `flatMap` calls followed by a single `map` (or all `foreach` calls). The call to `Try` breaks the chain. You get rid of the `Try` and use `map`, but two `map` calls can't be made into a single for-comprehension either.

`Try.flatMap` will catch errors that occur in the function passed to `flatMap`, so we can simplify the return type by calling `get` on the result of `bar`:

```
foo.map(a => a.map(c => bar(c).get))
```

We can get very close to a single for-comprehension by indenting two of them like this:

```
for {
  a <- foo
} yield for {
  c <- a
} yield bar(c).get
```

Which produces:

```
res12: scala.util.Try[Seq[String]] = Success(List(good, job))
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
foo.flatMap(a => Try(a.map(c => bar(c))))
```

is equivalent to:

```
for {
  a <- foo
} yield a.map(c => bar(c))
```

As to "flattening" the inner `map` into the same `for`-comprehension — wouldn't make sense if you want the result to be (i.e. 2 levels of `Try`):

```
Success(List(Success(good), Success(job)))
```

Although my intuition tells me you might want to flatten the `List[Try[String]]` to `List[String]` instead anyway (using e.g. `.map(_.toOption).flatten`), which I guess wingedsubmariner is also suggesting.