# Why does the code fail with type mismatch with for comprehension and Future?

Tags: scala

I have method but i can't understand why i have the type mismatch  error .
It my by close to this issue [Type Mismatch  For Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension) but i cant figure out why ??

i just want to create new list of (List[jsvalue], jsvalue) .

this is the error

```
Error:(41, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : List[(List[play.api.libs.json.JsValue], play.api.libs.json.JsValue)]
required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
    a <- x.map(_._1)
      ^
```

thanks 
miki

```
def test(future: Future[List[(List[JsValue], JsValue)]]) = {
  future.flatMap(x => {
    for {
      a <- x.map(_._1)
      b <- x.map(_._2)
    } yield (a, b)
  })
```

Comment: try `future.map`. With `flatMap` the `x => ...` function must return `Future`.

Comment: Yes, you (probably) want `map`, not `flatMap`. Also, note, that (provided, you make that change), the return value of your function is going to be `Future[(List[List[JSValue]], List[JSValue])]`, which, I suspect, might not be what you are actually looking for.

Comment: i want to get rid of the future ....

Comment: @MIkCode you can only do that using a blocking operation; see `Await.result`.