# For comprehension over Option array

Tags: arrays, scala, option-type, for-comprehension

I am getting compilation error:

```
Error:(64, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : Array[(String, String)]
 required: Option[?]
      y <- x
        ^
```

in a fragment:

```
val z = Some(Array("a"->"b", "c" -> "d"))
val l = for(
  x <- z;
  y <- x
) yield y
```

Why generator over Array does not produce items of the array? And where from requirement to have Option is coming from?

To be more ridiculous, if I replace "yield" with println(y) then it does compile.

Scala version: 2.10.6

Comment: The dupe is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/type-mismatch-on-scala-for-comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the way `for` expressions are translated into `map`, `flatmap` and `foreach` expressions. Let's first simplify your example:

```
val someArray: Some[Array[Int]] = Some(Array(1, 2, 3))
val l = for {
  array: Array[Int] <- someArray
  number: Int <- array
} yield number
```

In accordance with the relevant part of the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops), this first gets translated into

```
someArray.flatMap {case array => for (number <- array) yield number}
```

which in turn gets translated into

```
someArray.flatMap {case array => array.map{case number => number}}
```

The problem is that someArray.flatMap expects a function from `Array[Int]` to `Option[Array[Int]]`, whereas we've provided a function from `Array[Int]` to `Array[Int]`.

The reason the compilation error goes away if `yield number` is replaced by `println(number)` is that for loops are translated differently from for comprehensions: it will now be translated as `someArray.foreach{case array => array.foreach {case item => println(item)}}`, which doesn't have the same typing issues.

A possible solution is to begin by converting the Option to the kind of collection you want to end up with, so that its flatMap method will have the right signature:

```
val l = for {
  array: Array[Int] <- someArray.toArray
  number: Int <- array
} yield number
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the usual "option must be converted to mix monads" thing.

```
scala> for (x <- Option.option2Iterable(Some(List(1,2,3))); y <- x) yield y
res0: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Compare

```
scala> for (x <- Some(List(1,2,3)); y <- x) yield y
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
       for (x <- Some(List(1,2,3)); y <- x) yield y
                                      ^
```

to

```
scala> Some(List(1,2,3)) flatMap (is => is map (i => i))
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
       Some(List(1,2,3)) flatMap (is => is map (i => i))
                                           ^
```

or

```
scala> for (x <- Some(List(1,2,3)).toSeq; y <- x) yield y
res3: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```