# Scala compiler unhappy due to type issues (believe it is due to Option and List) in a for comprehension

Tags: scala, types

Okay, this is driving me nuts and I am certain I am missing something rather obvious here.  Hoping more eyes can clue me on my problem.  I have the following few lines of code where I am trying to break out a class that contains an Option[List] into individual entires:

```
case class Frob(t: String, ts: Option[List[String]])
case class FrobE(te: String, tes: String)
val f1 = Frob("G. Martin", Some(List("A", "B", "C")))
val f2 = Frob("A. Weir", Some(List("D", "E")))
val f3 = Frob("J. Tolkien", None)
val f4 = Frob("R. Jordan", None)
val f5 = Frob("G. Wolfe", Some(List("F", "Z")))
val fs = List(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)

val fe = for {
  f <- fs
  vs <- f.ts
  thing <- vs
} yield FrobE(f.t, thing)
```

But the compiler complains that the type of thing is List[FrobE] when it should be Option[Any].  Here is the error from ammonite:

```
cmd12.sc:4: type mismatch;
 found   : List[ammonite.$sess.cmd11.FrobE]
 required: Option[?]
  thing <- vs
        ^
Compilation Failed
```

I tried breaking this out into the equivalent flatMap/map chain, but am met with the same error (which is understandable):

```
@ fs.flatMap(f => f.ts.flatMap(vs => vs.map(t => FrobE(f.t, t))))
cmd12.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : List[ammonite.$sess.cmd11.FrobE]
 required: Option[?]
val fe2 = fs.flatMap(f => f.ts.flatMap(vs => vs.map(t => FrobE(f.t, t))))
                                                   ^
Compilation Failed
```

If I make a little intermediate case class and break this into two steps as follows, then it works as I had hoped.

```
case class FrobI(ti: String, tis: List[String])

val fd = for {
  f <- fs
  vs <- f.ts
} yield FrobI(f.t, vs)

val fe2 = for {
  d <- fd
  v <- d.tis
} yield FrobE(d.ti, v)
```

This tells me is it something I am overlooking with the combination of Option[List[]] but I am really missing it at the moment and would love some advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composing Option with List in for-comprehension gives type mismatch depending on order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/composing-option-with-list-in-for-comprehension-gives-type-mismatch-depending-on)

Comment: The problem is that `for` only work in one kind of `Monad` the best IMHO is not to use `for` and rather explicitly call combinators like `map` and `flatMap` like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ZuvWMlC0RAOHSrhRsRkYvQ/2 - PS: A `Option[List]` is usually a weird data type, since the `List` can just be empty so there is usually not much difference from a `None` to a `Some(Nil)` you may either just remove the `Option` which would simplify the code, or you may even rather use `Option[NonEmptyList]` which at least provide more information _(although is probably unnecessary here)_

Comment: Luis Miguel, thanks your solution worked exactly as I was hoping!

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
scala> case class Frob(t: String, ts: Option[List[String]])
     | case class FrobE(te: String, tes: String)
     | val f1 = Frob("G. Martin", Some(List("A", "B", "C")))
     | val f2 = Frob("A. Weir", Some(List("D", "E")))
     | val f3 = Frob("J. Tolkien", None)
     | val f4 = Frob("R. Jordan", None)
     | val f5 = Frob("G. Wolfe", Some(List("F", "Z")))
     | val fs = List(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)
     |
     | val fe = for {
     |   f <- fs
     |   thing <- f.ts.getOrElse(Nil)
     | } yield FrobE(f.t, thing)

val fe: List[FrobE] = List(FrobE(G. Martin,A), FrobE(G. Martin,B), FrobE(G. Martin,C), FrobE(A. Weir,D), 
                           FrobE(A. Weir,E), FrobE(G. Wolfe,F), FrobE(G. Wolfe,Z)
```