# restrictions on generator types in scala for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I'm trying to understand for comprehensions in scala.

When the first generator is a collection other than Option, the second generator can also be a collection other than Option:

```scala
case class D(p1: Option[Int], p2: List[Int])

val d = for
    p1 <- List(1)
    p2 <- List(2) 
yield D(Option(p1), List(p2))
assertEquals(d, List(D(Some(1), List(2))))
```

However, when the first generator is an Option, the second generator cannot be a collection other than Option (but it can be an Option):

```scala
val e = for
    p1 <- Option(1)
    // p2 <- List(2)   // cannot compile: Found: List[D], required: Option[Nothing]
yield D(Option(p1), List(2))
assertEquals(e, Some(D(Some(1), List(2))))
```

Note that the type of the second generator is List[Int], not List[D] as the Intellij Idea 2022.2.1 compiler says. Using scala 3.1.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composing Option with List in for-comprehension gives type mismatch depending on order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719592/composing-option-with-list-in-for-comprehension-gives-type-mismatch-depending-on)

Comment: Those are not generators, just sugar syntax over `flatMap` that explains why it works in the first case but not in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for-comprehension is a syntactic sugar for a sequence of `flatMap`s ending with a `map`.

Your first example is equivalent to this:

```
val d2 = List(1).flatMap(p1 => List(2).map(p2 => D(Option(p1), List(p2)))) // ok
```

If your second example would compile with that line uncommented, it would look like this:

```
val d3 = Option(1).flatMap(p1 => List(2).map(p2 => D(Option(p1), List(2)))) // compile error
```

As you can see, this is impossible because a `flatMap` on an `Option` must result in another `Option` not a `List[D]`. You see `List[D]` because this is the type of the right hand side of the function literal inside the `flatMap`: `List(2).map(p2 => D(Option(p1), List(2)))`.

The warning is correct in this case. You want an `Option` there, not a `List[D]`, but it's harder to understand the warning when using for-comprehension.

Generally, the type checker infers the *least upper bound*, which is `Option[Nothing]`, since `Nothing` is the subtype of every other type and `Option` is *covariant*. You get `Option[Nothing]` which is a subtype of `Option[Int]`, so it's type sound.

You can play around with this example [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/auKQ6oWlSgWPn3b4eTpTtg) on Scastie.